# Kafka producer how to catch ConnectException?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to figure out, how can I catch the exception, if the kafka server is not online.
I tried as following:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class KafkaProducerClient {

  private final static String TOPIC = "test";
  private final static String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "localhost:9092";

  private static Producer<String, String> createProducer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
        BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaExampleProducer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        LongSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        StringSerializer.class.getName());
    return new KafkaProducer<>(props);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    final Producer<String, String> producer = createProducer();
    try {

      final ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, "key", "Hello value ");
      RecordMetadata metadata = producer.send(record).get();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      producer.flush();
      producer.close();
    }
  }
}
```

I've got following error:

```
09:50:59.271 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Node -1 disconnected.
09:50:59.271 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
09:50:59.271 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.322 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.373 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.423 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.474 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.525 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.576 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.626 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.677 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.727 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.778 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.829 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.880 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.931 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:50:59.982 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:51:00.033 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
09:51:00.084 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Initialize connection to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
09:51:00.084 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Initiating connection to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
09:51:00.085 [kafka-producer-network-thread | KafkaExampleProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:106)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:444)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:398)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

as you can see, the error never got caught. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am facing the same issue right now, did you find solution for the error? I am not able to publish.